# Spark OutOfMemory issue after upgrading spark 3.2.1 -> 3.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory, amazon-emr

I am using AWS EMR. I recently upgraded EMR from 6.7 to 6.8(along with spark 3.2.1 to 3.3.0)

Since after I upgraded spark version, there seems to occur a OOM issue in my executors.
I did not change any code, only upgraded spark version.
What might have gone wrong?

I tried to find any difference using spark history server and monitored memory usage in EMR metrics but they all seem exatly the same.(same query plan, same CPU spec)

Anyone experience a similar issue when chaning the spark version?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the similar issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: yes I managed to resolve the issue. I have answered my own question below. Are you using something related to JDBC? @SanthoshTangudu

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing the same issue, please check jdbc config.
I think there was a change in fetch size in jdbc settings.

In EMR 6.7(pyspark 3.2.1), jdbc fetch size was set to negative maximum value which turn MySQL  into streaming mode.
However in EMR 6.8(pyspark 3.3.0) this setting disappeared. So I had to add

```
"fetchSize": f"{-2**31}",  # Integer.MIN_VALUE in JVM
```